# Incorrect MIME type on multiple files

Tags: javascript, html, css, tomcat

I have the following error on all my JS files:

`The script from “http://localhost:8086/home/js/classie.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`

I made the project using Intelij and TomCat web server, the code for the scripts inside HTML5 looks like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script-delete-word.js"></script>`

Why is this happening even thought I put `type="text/javascript` inside the script tag? The same problem is for the .css files too, I tried to change the location of js and css folder, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I made the project using Intelij

Your IDE isn't really relevant (unless you are using some sort of built-in web server that comes with it: if you are you should make that explicit in the question).

> Why is this happening

Something is wrong with your HTTP server. You haven't said what server you are using (or provided the code for it if you've written it yourself).

> Why is this happening even thought I put type="text/javascript inside the script tag?

The `type` attribute (when given a MIME type, the `module` value is a special case) tells the browser what to **expect** to get in the response to a request for the script's URL. This lets the browser avoid requesting scripts in programming languages it doesn't understand. The HTTP response headers are still authorative.

Comment: I'm using tomcat web server. What files should I check for the HTTP server? I didn't wrote the code for the web server.

Comment: http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Tomcat9-JSP-CSS-and-JS-not-loading-in-Firefox-td5093879.html suggests the cause might be a *filter*. I've never had reason to use Tomcat though.